# Showing specific anchors for each pictures of a lightbox in URL bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, hashtag

I have a lightbox where each pictures has an anchor.
But the anchor doesn't show the specific ID for each pictures, it appears like this in the URL bar :

- www.mywebsite.com/gallery.php#example/1
- www.mywebsite.com/gallery.php#example/2
- www.mywebsite.com/gallery.php#example/3

So, I wonder if it's possible to show in the URL bar the specific ID :

- www.mywebsite.com/gallery.php#bird
- www.mywebsite.com/gallery.php#dog
- www.mywebsite.com/gallery.php#cat

Any ideas ? Thanks.

*Html*

```
 <ul class="thumbnails" id="my-gallery">
        <li class="span2">
          <a href="images/full/example-bird.jpg" class="thumbnail" id="bird">
            <img src="images/thumbs/example-bird.jpg">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="span2">
          <a href="images/full/example-dog.jpg" class="thumbnail" id="dog">
            <img src="images/thumbs/example-dog.jpg">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="span2">
          <a href="images/full/example-cat.jpg" class="thumbnail" id="cat">
            <img src="images/thumbs/example-cat.jpg">
          </a>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

*Script*

```
$('#my-gallery li a').iLightBox({
    skin: 'dark',
    path: 'horizontal',
    fullViewPort: 'fill',
    infinite: true,
    linkId: 'example',
    overlay:{
        opacity: 1,
        blur: false
        },
    controls: {
        thumbnail: false
        },
        styles: {
            nextOffsetX: -45,
            prevOffsetX: -45
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code ?

Comment: No, because the result that I'm searching must be in the URL bar. I think there's no way to simulate a URL bar in fiddle.

Comment: its only about the window location hash, i think this may change even in fiddle

Comment: Try putting it on jsfiddle ( I think it will work there ). If not, you can provide a link to webpage. That way, you'll get enough attention :)

Comment: Thanks, I have create a simple page on my website with the lightbox : www.jasonpumo.com/test/stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to suggest an appropriate solution since I can't test iLightBox.

Referring to the iLightBox website, you could use the callback provided:

```
$('#my-gallery li a').iLightBox({
    skin: 'dark',
    path: 'horizontal',
    fullViewPort: 'fill',
    infinite: true,
    linkId: 'example',


    callback: {
        onShow:function(api) {
            $(location).attr("hash",$(api.currentElement).attr("id"));
        }
    },


    overlay:{
        opacity: 1,
        blur: false
        },
    controls: {
        thumbnail: false
        },
        styles: {
            nextOffsetX: -45,
            prevOffsetX: -45
        }
});
```

I highlighted the lines I inserted. My approach is using the callback for the onShow-event of the iLightBox for changing the Hash with jQuerys `$(location).attr("hash","value");`.

The problem is that I'm not sure if onShow is the correct event to hook into and if currentElement is in fact the anchor or not. This is something you have to find out yourself. I'm sorry.

**Edit**

I think if you're doing it my way, you have to remove that `linkId` from your parameters.

**Edit**

I tried something on the test page you linked above.

This code works fine for me if I paste it into the console:

```
$('#deeplinking_looping_gallery li a').iLightBox({
    skin: 'metro-black',
    path: 'horizontal',
    fullViewPort: 'fill',
    infinite: true,
    overlay: {
        opacity: 1,
        blur: false
    },
    callback: {
        onBeforeLoad:function(api) {
            $(location).attr("hash",$("#deeplinking_looping_gallery li").eq(api.currentItem).children("a").data("caption"));
        }
    },
    controls: {
        thumbnail: false
    },
    styles: {
        nextOffsetX: -45,
        prevOffsetX: -45
    }
});
```

**Edit**

Loading an image at page load should be possible with this line of code:

```
$("a[data-caption='" + $(location).attr("hash").substr(1) + "']").trigger("click");
```

It triggers the click event for the appropriate anchor (like if you click it with your mouse).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work.. I think it's just a question of matching the linkId with the ID in '#my-gallery li a'

Comment: In fact, I want the deep linking to give specific names instead of the numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SVSchmidt but how can I load directly the current image in lightbox with the link ? for example : www.jasonpumo.com/test/stack#dog  If it's impossible, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Added a suggestion to my answer!

Comment: Many thanks for your time and your answers, everything seems good now :) Thanks again !

Comment: One more quick question : the last line of code that you wrote can be completed by a trackevent from Google Analytics in order to track image views ?

Comment: I think it should work. Or you could try to track the URL hash since they're associated with the images now. But I'm sorry, I'm not an expert in Google Analytics.

Comment: Yes, thanks :) it's working good : `callback: {
onBeforeLoad: function(api) { $(location).attr("hash",$("#deeplinking_looping_gallery li").eq(api.currentItem).children("a").data("caption")); _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash]);`