# Display a specific title instead of a number after the hashtag in URL bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, hashtag

I have a script where 'linkId' add an anchor in the URL bar by clicking on a picture of a gallery. But it displays automatically a number according to the current picture (#1, #2, #3, #4, ...).
I want 'linkId' to display a specific title for each picture after the hashtag (#title-of-the-picture), maybe by indicating the name or the title of the picture but I don't know how to match 'linkId' with this.
Any ideas ? Thanks.

HTML

```
<ul class="thumbnails" id="my-gallery">
    <li class="span2">
      <a href="images/full/example-bird.jpg" class="thumbnail" name="bird">
        <img src="images/thumbs/example-bird.jpg">
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Script

```
$('#my-gallery li a').iLightBox({
        linkId: ''
    });
```

Comment: Answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832905/showing-specific-anchors-for-each-pictures-of-a-lightbox-in-url-bar